# Unable to create visualization using curl command in elaticearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-6, kibana-6

I am trying to create visualization using curl command. I am using elasticsearch 6.2.3. I am able to create the same in elasticsearch 5.6.8.
I am using this command 
`curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/.kibana/visualization/vis1 -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -d @vis1.json`
It is showing this error :

```html
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting mapping update to [.kibana] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [visualization, doc]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting mapping update to [.kibana] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [visualization, doc]"},"status":400}
```

Contents of vis1.json:

```html
{
      "title": "vis1",
      "visState": "{\"title\":\"vis1\",\"type\":\"table\",\"params\":{\"perPage\":10,\"showMeticsAtAllLevels\":false,\"showPartialRows\":false,\"showTotal\":false,\"sort\":{\"columnIndex\":null,\"direction\":null},\"totalFunc\":\"sum\"},\"aggs\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"enabled\":true,\"type\":\"count\",\"schema\":\"metric\",\"params\":{}},{\"id\":\"2\",\"enabled\":true,\"type\":\"date_histogram\",\"schema\":\"split\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"UsageEndDate\",\"interval\":\"M\",\"customInterval\":\"2h\",\"min_doc_count\":1,\"extended_bounds\":{},\"row\":false}},{\"id\":\"3\",\"enabled\":true,\"type\":\"terms\",\"schema\":\"bucket\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"ProductName.keyword\",\"otherBucket\":false,\"otherBucketLabel\":\"Other\",\"missingBucket\":false,\"missingBucketLabel\":\"Missing\",\"size\":5,\"order\":\"desc\",\"orderBy\":\"1\"}}]}",
      "uiStateJSON": "{\"vis\":{\"params\":{\"sort\":{\"columnIndex\":null,\"direction\":null}}}}",
      "description": "",
      "version": 1,
      "kibanaSavedObjectMeta": {
        "searchSourceJSON": "{\"index\":\"4eb9f840-3969-11e8-ae19-552e148747c3\",\"filter\":[],\"query\":{\"language\":\"lucene\",\"query\":\"\"}}"
      }
    }
```

This is working fine in elasticearch 5.6.8 but not in 6.2.3.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Kibana 6, the mapping of the `.kibana`index [has changed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/migrating-6.0-index.html) in order to satisfy the upcoming "one mapping per index" breaking change.

You can try this way instead:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/.kibana/doc/visualization:vis1 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @vis1.json
```

Also the `vis1.json` file needs to be changed a little bit (the content needs to be moved to the `visualization` sub-section), like this:

```
{
  "type": "visualization",
  "updated_at": "2018-04-10T10:00:00.000Z",
  "visualization": {
    "title": "vis1",
    "visState": "{\"title\":\"vis1\",\"type\":\"table\",\"params\":{\"perPage\":10,\"showMeticsAtAllLevels\":false,\"showPartialRows\":false,\"showTotal\":false,\"sort\":{\"columnIndex\":null,\"direction\":null},\"totalFunc\":\"sum\"},\"aggs\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"enabled\":true,\"type\":\"count\",\"schema\":\"metric\",\"params\":{}},{\"id\":\"2\",\"enabled\":true,\"type\":\"date_histogram\",\"schema\":\"split\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"UsageEndDate\",\"interval\":\"M\",\"customInterval\":\"2h\",\"min_doc_count\":1,\"extended_bounds\":{},\"row\":false}},{\"id\":\"3\",\"enabled\":true,\"type\":\"terms\",\"schema\":\"bucket\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"ProductName.keyword\",\"otherBucket\":false,\"otherBucketLabel\":\"Other\",\"missingBucket\":false,\"missingBucketLabel\":\"Missing\",\"size\":5,\"order\":\"desc\",\"orderBy\":\"1\"}}]}",
    "uiStateJSON": "{\"vis\":{\"params\":{\"sort\":{\"columnIndex\":null,\"direction\":null}}}}",
    "description": "",
    "version": 1,
    "kibanaSavedObjectMeta": {
      "searchSourceJSON": "{\"index\":\"4eb9f840-3969-11e8-ae19-552e148747c3\",\"filter\":[],\"query\":{\"language\":\"lucene\",\"query\":\"\"}}"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I did that. It created Visualization but when I am Opening the visualization it is showing "Could not locate that visualization (id: vis1)"

Comment: My bad, the id was wrong, I've updated the curl command, please try again

Comment: Yes Sir. Thank You. :) You are awesome.

Comment: Sir, I want to know, how can I use this same json file in another elasticsearch server.

Comment: Since this is a different subject, I suggest you create another question referencing this one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49751058/using-exported-visualization-json-to-bring-the-same-visualization-in-another-ela

Comment: sir please look at my issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49751058/using-exported-visualization-json-to-bring-the-same-visualization-in-another-ela