# How do I import a Kibana 6 visualization into elasticsearch 6 without using the Kibana UI?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-6

I am trying to import a Kibana 6 visualization into Elasticsearch 6, to be viewed in Kibana.  I am trying to do this with a curl command, or essentially a script without going through the Kibana UI.  This is the command I’m using:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/.kibana/doc/visualization:vis1 -H 
'Content-Type: application/json' -d @visual1.json
```

And this is visual1.json:

```
{
"type": "visualization",
"visualization": {
"title": "Logins",
"visState": "{\"title\":\"Logins\",\"type\":\"histogram\",\"params\":{\"type\":\"histogram\",\"grid\":{\"categoryLines\":false,\"style\":{\"color\":\"#eee\"}},\"categoryAxes\":[{\"id\":\"CategoryAxis-1\",\"type\":\"category\",\"position\":\"bottom\",\"show\":true,\"style\":{},\"scale\":{\"type\":\"linear\"},\"labels\":{\"show\":true,\"truncate\":100},\"title\":{}}],\"valueAxes\":[{\"id\":\"ValueAxis-1\",\"name\":\"LeftAxis-1\",\"type\":\"value\",\"position\":\"left\",\"show\":true,\"style\":{},\"scale\":{\"type\":\"linear\",\"mode\":\"normal\"},\"labels\":{\"show\":true,\"rotate\":0,\"filter\":false,\"truncate\":100},\"title\":{\"text\":\"Count\"}}],\"seriesParams\":[{\"show\":\"true\",\"type\":\"histogram\",\"mode\":\"stacked\",\"data\":{\"label\":\"Count\",\"id\":\"1\"},\"valueAxis\":\"ValueAxis-1\",\"drawLinesBetweenPoints\":true,\"showCircles\":true}],\"addTooltip\":true,\"addLegend\":true,\"legendPosition\":\"right\",\"times\":[],\"addTimeMarker\":false},\"aggs\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"enabled\":true,\"type\":\"count\",\"schema\":\"metric\",\"params\":{}},{\"id\":\"2\",\"enabled\":true,\"type\":\"terms\",\"schema\":\"segment\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"principal.keyword\",\"otherBucket\":true,\"otherBucketLabel\":\"Other\",\"missingBucket\":false,\"missingBucketLabel\":\"Missing\",\"size\":5,\"order\":\"desc\",\"orderBy\":\"1\"}}]}",
"uiStateJSON": "{}",
"description": "",
"version": 1,
"kibanaSavedObjectMeta": {
  "searchSourceJSON": "{\"index\":\"def097e0-550f-11e8-9266-93ce640e5839\”,\”filter\":[{\"meta\":{\"index\":\"def097e0-550f-11e8-9266-93ce640e5839\”,\”negate\":false,\"disabled\":false,\"alias\":null,\"type\":\"phrase\",\"key\":\"requestType.keyword\",\"value\":\"ALOG\”,\”params\":{\"query\":\"AUTH_LOGIN\",\"type\":\"phrase\"}},\"query\":{\"match\":{\"requestType.keyword\":{\"query\":\"AUTH_LOGIN\",\"type\":\"phrase\"}}},\"$state\":{\"store\":\"appState\"}}],\"query\":{\"query\":\"\",\"language\":\"lucene\"}}"
}
}
}
```

Now a couple things to note about the curl command and this json file.  The index I push the visualization to is .kibana.  I found that when I pushed these to other index’s such as “test”, my data would not show up as a stored object in Kibana, and thus wouldn’t show up on the visualization tab.  When I PUT to .kibana with this syntax ‘.kibana/doc/visualization:vis1 ‘, my object shows up on the visualization tab.

Now concerning the json file.  Note that when you export a visualization from Kibana 6, it doesn’t look like this.  It looks like:

```
{
"_id": "vis1",
"_type": "visualization",
"_source": {
  "title": "Logins",
  "visState": "{\"title\":\"Logins\",\"type\":\"histogram\",\"params\":{\"type\":\"histogram\",\"grid\":{\"categoryLines\":false,\"style\":{\"color\":\"#eee\"}},\"categoryAxes\":[{\"id\":\"CategoryAxis-1\",\"type\":\"category\",\"position\":\"bottom\",\"show\":true,\"style\":{},\"scale\":{\"type\":\"linear\"},\"labels\":{\"show\":true,\"truncate\":100},\"title\":{}}],\"valueAxes\":[{\"id\":\"ValueAxis-1\",\"name\":\"LeftAxis-1\",\"type\":\"value\",\"position\":\"left\",\"show\":true,\"style\":{},\"scale\":{\"type\":\"linear\",\"mode\":\"normal\"},\"labels\":{\"show\":true,\"rotate\":0,\"filter\":false,\"truncate\":100},\"title\":{\"text\":\"Count\"}}],\"seriesParams\":[{\"show\":\"true\",\"type\":\"histogram\",\"mode\":\"stacked\",\"data\":{\"label\":\"Count\",\"id\":\"1\"},\"valueAxis\":\"ValueAxis-1\",\"drawLinesBetweenPoints\":true,\"showCircles\":true}],\"addTooltip\":true,\"addLegend\":true,\"legendPosition\":\"right\",\"times\":[],\"addTimeMarker\":false},\"aggs\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"enabled\":true,\"type\":\"count\",\"schema\":\"metric\",\"params\":{}},{\"id\":\"2\",\"enabled\":true,\"type\":\"terms\",\"schema\":\"segment\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"principal.keyword\",\"otherBucket\":true,\"otherBucketLabel\":\"Other\",\"missingBucket\":false,\"missingBucketLabel\":\"Missing\",\"size\":5,\"order\":\"desc\",\"orderBy\":\"1\"}}]}",
  "uiStateJSON": "{}",
  "description": "",
  "version": 1,
  "kibanaSavedObjectMeta": {
    "searchSourceJSON": "{\"index\":\"def097e0-550f-11e8-9266-93ce640e5839\",\"filter\":[{\"meta\":{\"index\":\"def097e0-550f-11e8-9266-93ce640e5839\",\"negate\":false,\"disabled\":false,\"alias\":null,\"type\":\"phrase\",\"key\":\"requestType.keyword\",\"value\":\"LOG\",\"params\":{\"query\":\"LOG\",\"type\":\"phrase\"}},\"query\":{\"match\":{\"requestType.keyword\":{\"query\":\"LOG\",\"type\":\"phrase\"}}},\"$state\":{\"store\":\"appState\"}}],\"query\":{\"query\":\"\",\"language\":\"lucene\"}}"
  }
}
}
```

Note the first few lines.  I found from this link [Unable to create visualization using curl command in elaticearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49747935/unable-to-create-visualization-using-curl-command-in-elaticearch) that you have to modify the json export in order to import it.  Seems strange right?

Anyway, then I’ve had two errors on the actual visualization object once in Kibana.  The first was that “The index pattern associated with this object no longer exists.”  I was able to get around this by creating an index pattern with the id referenced in the searchSourceJson of my visualization.  I had to do this within the Kibana UI, so technically this solution would not work for me.  In any case, I created an index with a document in it by calling

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/test57/_doc/1" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
"user" : "kimchy",
"post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
"message" : "trying out Elasticsearch"
}
'
```

And then in the Kibana UI, created an index pattern and gave it the custom index pattern ID def097e0-550f-11e8-9266-93ce640e5839.

Now when I go try to view my visualization, I get a new error.  “A field associated with this object no longer exists in the index pattern.”
I am guessing this has something to do with me pushing a random object into the index, but even with debug settings on for elastic and kibana, I don’t really get enough information to fix this problem.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great!  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the fields you reference in your visualization definition are also present in the Kibana index pattern (Kibana main screen > Management > Index Patterns).  The easiest way to do that would be to include said fields in the dummy index you created and then 'refresh field list' in the Kibana Index Patterns screen.

You can do this via CLI by creating a document of _type index-pattern in the .kibana index.

Comment: So this still would be working within the Kibana UI which does not fix my issue, but also how do I tell which fields from my visual1 object are important?  Is it all of the fields inside the "visualization" field?  So title, visState etc...

Comment: The fields that you need to ensure are present in the Kibana index pattern are the elements in visState.params.field.  For your example above it looks like that would just be 'principal.keyword'.

I've revised the answer to provide how to set the index pattern without using the web UI.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to import through kibana endpoint using api [saved_objects](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.8/saved-objects-api-create.html).
This needs to modify the exported json wrapping it inside `{"attributes":....}`

Base on your example it should be something like:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:5601/api/saved_objects/visualization/myvisualisation?overwrite=true" -H "kbn-xsrf: reporting" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{"attributes":{
    "title": "Logins",
    "visState": "{\"title\":\"Logins\",\"type\":\"histogram\",\"params\":{\"type\":\"histogram\",\"grid\":{\"categoryLines\":false,\"style\":{\"color\":\"#eee\"}},\"categoryAxes\":[{\"id\":\"CategoryAxis-1\",\"type\":\"category\",\"position\":\"bottom\",\"show\":true,\"style\":{},\"scale\":{\"type\":\"linear\"},\"labels\":{\"show\":true,\"truncate\":100},\"title\":{}}],\"valueAxes\":[{\"id\":\"ValueAxis-1\",\"name\":\"LeftAxis-1\",\"type\":\"value\",\"position\":\"left\",\"show\":true,\"style\":{},\"scale\":{\"type\":\"linear\",\"mode\":\"normal\"},\"labels\":{\"show\":true,\"rotate\":0,\"filter\":false,\"truncate\":100},\"title\":{\"text\":\"Count\"}}],\"seriesParams\":[{\"show\":\"true\",\"type\":\"histogram\",\"mode\":\"stacked\",\"data\":{\"label\":\"Count\",\"id\":\"1\"},\"valueAxis\":\"ValueAxis-1\",\"drawLinesBetweenPoints\":true,\"showCircles\":true}],\"addTooltip\":true,\"addLegend\":true,\"legendPosition\":\"right\",\"times\":[],\"addTimeMarker\":false},\"aggs\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"enabled\":true,\"type\":\"count\",\"schema\":\"metric\",\"params\":{}},{\"id\":\"2\",\"enabled\":true,\"type\":\"terms\",\"schema\":\"segment\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"principal.keyword\",\"otherBucket\":true,\"otherBucketLabel\":\"Other\",\"missingBucket\":false,\"missingBucketLabel\":\"Missing\",\"size\":5,\"order\":\"desc\",\"orderBy\":\"1\"}}]}",
    "uiStateJSON": "{}",
    "description": "",
    "version": 1,
    "kibanaSavedObjectMeta": {
      "searchSourceJSON": "{\"index\":\"def097e0-550f-11e8-9266-93ce640e5839\",\"filter\":[{\"meta\":{\"index\":\"def097e0-550f-11e8-9266-93ce640e5839\",\"negate\":false,\"disabled\":false,\"alias\":null,\"type\":\"phrase\",\"key\":\"requestType.keyword\",\"value\":\"LOG\",\"params\":{\"query\":\"LOG\",\"type\":\"phrase\"}},\"query\":{\"match\":{\"requestType.keyword\":{\"query\":\"LOG\",\"type\":\"phrase\"}}},\"$state\":{\"store\":\"appState\"}}],\"query\":{\"query\":\"\",\"language\":\"lucene\"}}"
    }
  }
}
'
```